# Tracking traffic of individual microsites Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a web site which has many microsites.

I want to use Google Analytics to track the traffic of each individual Microsite as opposed to tracking traffic of the whole site?

I have looked at Google Tag Manager, but I am not sure if this is the right solution - how can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's two basic ways in which this can be done:

- If you don't care about inter-microsite traffic, you can just create a different GA property for every microsite and use Google Tag Manager to create your GA tracking tag with the right property ID depending on the hostname (using a [lookup table variable](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106899), for example).
- If you want to be able to see traffic flow between your microsites (i.e. not have a visitor navigating from one site to another show up as a referral but as the same session), then you should use the same GA property for all sites and set up [cross domain tracking](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en). Then inside your GA property, you can set up different views based on the hostname dimension of the hits.